# ValueError with matmul Single Class Sep. mismatch in its core dimension 0

Tags: machine-learning, python

**Single Class Separation Problem**

Creating custom NMF function with custom weights updates (nmf_updateH) and (nmf_updateW). The goal is to compute Single Class Separation (NMF).

**Effort to update H is working ok. Effort to update W on specific condition is causing a  : Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 131 is different from 60).

This is happening on following code section for the W calculation, W = W * ((X / (W @ H)) @ H.T) / (ones_matrix @ H.T):

```
119     W = nmf_updateW(X, activation, H, num_components)
    121 WH = W @ H
    122 error = np.sum(X * np.log((X + eps) / (WH + eps)) - X + WH)        

Cell In[75], line 9, in nmf_updateW(X, W, H, num_components)
      7 F, T = X.shape
      8 ones_matrix = np.ones((F, T))
----> 9 W = W * ((X / (W @ H)) @ H.T) / (ones_matrix @ H.T)
```

**Test Case Works, but Production Code Fails**

Here is a test case on the function in error, namely, nmf_updateW(). I setup the conditions that match the overall production code run. The ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 131 is different from 60) and the matrix that need to work together are in the function nmf_updateW() at W = W * ((X / (W @ H)) @ H.T) / (ones_matrix @ H.T) :

```
    W = W * ((X / (W @ H)) @ H.T) / (ones_matrix @ H.T) 
   #W = (513,60) * ((X / (513,60 @ H (131, 129)) @ (129, 131))
```

The code works for other passes but fails on this scenario:

```
def nmf_updateH(X, W, H, num_components, eps=1e-20):
    F, T = X.shape
    ones_matrix = np.ones((F, T))
    H = H * (W.T @ (X / (W @ H + eps))) / (W.T @ ones_matrix)
    return H
def nmf_updateW(X, W, H, num_components):
    F, T = X.shape
    ones_matrix = np.ones((F, T))
    W = W * ((X / (W @ H)) @ H.T) / (ones_matrix @ H.T)    
    return W, ones_matrix

F, T = S.shape
W = np.random.rand(F, num_components)
H = np.random.rand(num_components, T)
H = np.random.rand(num_components, S.shape[1])[0:513,:]

W = np.concatenate((W_S_model, W_N_model), axis=1)[0:513,:]

print('----')
print('WS', W_S_model.shape)
print('WN', W_N_model.shape)
print('W',W.shape)
print('H',H.shape)
print('signal', S.shape)
_W, ones_matrix = nmf_updateW(S, W, H, num_components)

print('ones_matrix', ones_matrix.shape)
print(((S / (W @ H)) @ H.T) / (ones_matrix @ H.T))
print('_W',_W.shape)
```

**Machine Learning Code**

````
def nmf_updateH(X, W, H, num_components, eps=1e-20):
    F, T = X.shape
    ones_matrix = np.ones((F, T))
    H = H * (W.T @ (X / (W @ H + eps))) / (W.T @ ones_matrix)
    return H

def nmf_updateW(X, W, H, num_components):
    F, T = X.shape
    ones_matrix = np.ones((F, T))
    W = W * ((X / (W @ H)) @ H.T) / (ones_matrix @ H.T)    
    return W

def nmf(X, num_components, provide=False, activation=0, max_iterations=1000, tolerance=1e-5, eps=1e-20):
    if not check_non_negativity(X):
        raise ValueError("matrix X must be non-negative.")
     
    F, T = X.shape
    W = np.random.rand(F, num_components)
    H = np.random.rand(num_components, T)
    if (provide): 
        H = np.random.rand(num_components, X.shape[1])[0:513,:]
    nmf_prev_error = np.inf    
    for i in range(max_iterations): #x, w, h = : 0.5 * np.square(no.linalg.morm(x-w@h))
        H = nmf_updateH(X, W, H, num_components, eps)
        W = nmf_updateW(X, W, H, num_components)
        if (provide): 
            W = nmf_updateW(X, activation, H, num_components)
            
        WH = W @ H
        error = np.sum(X * np.log((X + eps) / (WH + eps)) - X + WH)        
        if np.abs(nmf_prev_error - error) < tolerance:
            break
        
        nmf_prev_error = error         
        H = np.abs(H)
        W = np.abs(W)
    return W, H, error
```
````